# Compiling frama-c-Neon-20140301.tar.gz on Ubuntu

Tags: frama-c

I have problem with compiling newest version of Frama-C. 
What I have done:

```
wget http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-Neon-20140301.tar.gz
tar -xzf frama-c-Neon-20140301.tar.gz 
cd frama-c-Neon-20140301/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
```

After a minute I get this

```
Packing      lib/plugins/Wp.cma
Linking      bin/toplevel.byte
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x4529f0): undefined reference to `terminate_process'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x4529f4): undefined reference to `ml_usleep'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x4529f8): undefined reference to `getperfcount'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x4529fc): undefined reference to `getperfcount1024'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x452a00): undefined reference to `address_of_value'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x452a04): undefined reference to `set_round_nearest_even'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x452a08): undefined reference to `single_precision_of_string'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x452a0c): undefined reference to `round_to_float'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x452a10): undefined reference to `set_round_upward'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x452a14): undefined reference to `set_round_downward'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x452a18): undefined reference to `float_is_negative'
/tmp/ccLwedhX.o:(.data+0x452a1c): undefined reference to `float_compare_total'
src/buckx/buckx_c.o: In function `round_to_float(long)':
buckx_c.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `caml_copy_double(double)'
src/buckx/buckx_c.o: In function `single_precision_of_string(long)':
buckx_c.c:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to `caml_string_length(long)'
buckx_c.c:(.text+0x194): undefined reference to `caml_copy_double(double)'
buckx_c.c:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `caml_failwith(char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
File "_none_", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Error while building custom runtime system
make: *** [bin/toplevel.byte] Error 2
```

I am using gcc 4.8.1, Ubuntu 12.04, ocaml 3.12.1

UPDATE:
VERBOSEMAKE=yes make

```
ocamlc.opt -w +a-4-6-9-41-44-45  -annot  -g -I src/misc -I src/ai -I src/memory_state -I src/toplevel -I src/slicing_types -I src/pdg_types -I src/kernel -I src/logic -I src/lib -I src/printer -I src/project -I src/type -I src/buckx -I src/gui -I external -I cil/src -I cil/src/ext -I cil/src/frontc -I cil/src/logic -I cil/ocamlutil -I lib/plugins -I lib     -linkall -custom -o bin/toplevel.byte nums.cma unix.cma bigarray.cma str.cma dynlink.cma   lib/graph.cmo src/buckx/buckx_c.o   external/unmarshal.cmo external/unmarshal_nums.cmo external/sysutil.cmo src/lib/dynlink_common_interface.cmo src/type/structural_descr.cmo src/type/type.cmo src/type/descr.cmo src/lib/FCSet.cmo src/lib/FCMap.cmo src/lib/FCHashtbl.cmo src/lib/extlib.cmo src/lib/pretty_utils.cmo src/lib/hook.cmo src/lib/bag.cmo src/lib/indexer.cmo src/lib/vector.cmo src/lib/bitvector.cmo src/lib/qstack.cmo src/lib/integer.cmo src/lib/filepath.cmo src/kernel/config.cmo src/kernel/log.cmo src/kernel/cmdline.cmo src/project/project_skeleton.cmo src/type/datatype.cmo src/kernel/journal.cmo src/project/state.cmo src/project/state_dependency_graph.cmo src/project/state_topological.cmo src/project/state_selection.cmo src/project/project.cmo src/project/state_builder.cmo src/kernel/typed_parameter.cmo src/kernel/dynamic.cmo src/kernel/parameter_customize.cmo src/kernel/parameter_state.cmo src/kernel/parameter_builder.cmo src/kernel/plugin.cmo src/kernel/kernel.cmo src/kernel/emitter.cmo src/lib/floating_point.cmo src/lib/rangemap.cmo src/lib/binary_cache.cmo external/hptmap.cmo src/lib/hptset.cmo src/printer/printer_builder.cmo cil/src/cilmsg.cmo cil/ocamlutil/alpha.cmo cil/ocamlutil/cilconfig.cmo cil/src/cil_datatype.cmo cil/src/cil_state_builder.cmo cil/src/logic/utf8_logic.cmo cil/src/machdep_x86_16.cmo cil/src/machdep_x86_32.cmo cil/src/machdep_x86_64.cmo cil/src/machdep_ppc_32.cmo cil/src/cil_const.cmo cil/src/logic/logic_env.cmo cil/src/escape.cmo cil/src/logic/logic_const.cmo cil/src/cil.cmo src/printer/cil_printer.cmo src/printer/cil_descriptive_printer.cmo cil/src/frontc/errorloc.cmo cil/src/frontc/cabs.cmo cil/src/ext/expcompare.cmo cil/src/frontc/cabs_debug.cmo cil/src/frontc/cabshelper.cmo cil/src/logic/logic_utils.cmo cil/src/logic/logic_builtin.cmo cil/src/logic/logic_print.cmo cil/src/logic/logic_parser.cmo cil/src/logic/logic_lexer.cmo cil/src/frontc/lexerhack.cmo cil/src/mergecil.cmo cil/src/rmtmps.cmo cil/src/logic/logic_typing.cmo cil/src/frontc/cprint.cmo cil/src/frontc/cabscond.cmo cil/src/frontc/cabsvisit.cmo cil/src/frontc/cabs2cil.cmo cil/src/frontc/clexer.cmo cil/src/frontc/cparser.cmo cil/src/logic/logic_preprocess.cmo cil/src/frontc/frontc.cmo cil/src/ext/callgraph.cmo cil/src/ext/dataflow.cmo cil/src/ext/oneret.cmo cil/src/ext/cfg.cmo src/buckx/buckx.cmo src/kernel/ast_info.cmo src/kernel/ast.cmo src/kernel/globals.cmo src/kernel/kernel_function.cmo src/logic/property.cmo src/logic/property_status.cmo src/logic/annotations.cmo src/printer/printer.cmo src/kernel/stmts_graph.cmo cil/src/ext/ordered_stmt.cmo cil/src/ext/dataflows.cmo cil/src/ext/dataflow2.cmo cil/src/ext/usedef.cmo cil/src/ext/liveness.cmo cil/src/ext/reachingdefs.cmo cil/src/ext/availexpslv.cmo cil/src/ext/rmciltmps.cmo cil/src/ext/deadcodeelim.cmo src/kernel/dominators.cmo src/logic/description.cmo src/logic/statuses_by_call.cmo src/kernel/alarms.cmo src/kernel/messages.cmo src/ai/abstract_interp.cmo src/ai/int_Base.cmo src/kernel/unicode.cmo src/misc/service_graph.cmo src/ai/ival.cmo src/misc/bit_utils.cmo src/ai/lattice_Interval_Set.cmo src/ai/base.cmo src/ai/origin.cmo src/ai/map_Lattice.cmo src/ai/trace.cmo src/memory_state/locations.cmo src/memory_state/value_messages.cmo src/kernel/cilE.cmo src/memory_state/int_Interv.cmo src/memory_state/int_Interv_Map.cmo src/memory_state/tr_offset.cmo src/memory_state/offsetmap.cmo src/memory_state/offsetmap_bitwise.cmo src/memory_state/lmap.cmo src/memory_state/lmap_bitwise.cmo src/memory_state/function_Froms.cmo src/memory_state/cvalue.cmo src/memory_state/widen_type.cmo src/kernel/visitor.cmo cil/src/frontc/cabsbranches.cmo src/kernel/loop.cmo src/memory_state/inout_type.cmo src/pdg_types/pdgIndex.cmo src/pdg_types/pdgTypes.cmo src/pdg_types/pdgMarks.cmo src/slicing_types/slicingInternals.cmo src/slicing_types/slicingTypes.cmo src/memory_state/value_types.cmo src/kernel/db.cmo src/kernel/command.cmo src/kernel/task.cmo src/kernel/file.cmo src/logic/translate_lightweight.cmo src/kernel/unroll_loops.cmo src/misc/filter.cmo src/kernel/special_hooks.cmo src/logic/logic_interp.cmo src/logic/infer_annotations.cmo src/logic/allocates.cmo lib/plugins/Metrics.cmo lib/plugins/Syntactic_callgraph.cmo lib/plugins/Value.cmo lib/plugins/Occurrence.cmo lib/plugins/RteGen.cmo lib/plugins/From.cmo lib/plugins/Users.cmo lib/plugins/Constant_Propagation.cmo lib/plugins/Postdominators.cmo lib/plugins/Inout.cmo lib/plugins/Semantic_callgraph.cmo lib/plugins/Impact.cmo lib/plugins/Pdg.cmo lib/plugins/Scope.cmo lib/plugins/Sparecode.cmo lib/plugins/Slicing.cmo src/kernel/boot.cmo
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x4529f0): undefined reference to `terminate_process'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x4529f4): undefined reference to `ml_usleep'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x4529f8): undefined reference to `getperfcount'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x4529fc): undefined reference to `getperfcount1024'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x452a00): undefined reference to `address_of_value'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x452a04): undefined reference to `set_round_nearest_even'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x452a08): undefined reference to `single_precision_of_string'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x452a0c): undefined reference to `round_to_float'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x452a10): undefined reference to `set_round_upward'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x452a14): undefined reference to `set_round_downward'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x452a18): undefined reference to `float_is_negative'
/tmp/ccg2Te0Y.o:(.data+0x452a1c): undefined reference to `float_compare_total'
src/buckx/buckx_c.o: In function `round_to_float(long)':
buckx_c.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `caml_copy_double(double)'
src/buckx/buckx_c.o: In function `single_precision_of_string(long)':
buckx_c.c:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to `caml_string_length(long)'
buckx_c.c:(.text+0x194): undefined reference to `caml_copy_double(double)'
buckx_c.c:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `caml_failwith(char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
File "_none_", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Error while building custom runtime system
make: *** [bin/toplevel.byte] Error 2
```

VERBOSEMAKE gives almost the same information.

Comment: Please type `VERBOSEMAKE=yes make` and include the output in your question. The commands that have been tried will be displayed. Since your compilation was going well until the link, this should be only the link command.

Comment: Thanks. The additional information given by VERBOSEMAKE=yes is the attempted command “ocamlc.opt …”, which will be crucial to whomever is able to help you with this.

Comment: It seems as though your OCaml installation is buggy, and misses most (all?) C primitives. How did you install OCaml ?